# Why prefer Plugman over Cordova CLI for embedded projects?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, plugman

I'm working on a iOS-only project with an embedded Cordova Web view. The Cordova docs say I should use Plugman instead of the Cordova CLI. But why? When I add my platform, Cordova automatically detects and adds plugins. To use Plugman, I would have to remove each plugin and re-add it. And the only difference - that I found - is that Plugman copies the plugins to platforms/ios/cordova/plugins, whereas Cordova keeps them in the plugins directory. And Plugman still copies sources for other platforms! Why use it? The app can load plugins either way, so why prefer Plugman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not preferred, it's the only available tool when using a single-platform workflow. You don't use `cordova` (and its `platform`, `plugin` CLI) at all, only `cordova-ios`.

To create an iOS project, run `node_modules/cordova-ios/bin/create myproj`.

Then use `plugman install --platform ios --project myproj --plugin cordova-plugin-device`. This will copy the plugin's JS interface to the myproj/platform_www. Since you're using your own Xcode project, you won't be using the generated "myproj" project at all - it's just a staging area for the Crodova runtime files. So you need to add the plugins' source files to your project manually, and then copy its `platform_www` files to your own www directory, where your embedded Web view can load them.

This should have been covered in more detail in the Cordova guides.

Answer (score 0):

Found this in the latest docs here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/plugman.html

> If you use a cross-platform workflow, you use the cordova CLI utility to add plugins, as described in The Command-Line Interface. The CLI modifies plugins for all specified platforms at once.
>
> If you use a platform-centered workflow, you use a lower-level Plugman command-line interface, separately for each targeted platform.

Early on in my app development (maybe Cordova 3.x or so), I would start working in the individual platforms rather than at the top level -- and then all my changes would be overwritten when I did a `cordova build`. Super frustrating -- so I ended up only working at the top level rather than in the `/platforms/` directories. I've never used Plugman. So maybe that's a data point in favor of the CLI. :-)

Comment: I think I understand it a little better now… You don’t use Cordova CLI at all for single-platform projects. You just install cordova-ios (or cordova-android) and then Plugman is the only available plugin manager.